# Slide Up Layout and Stretch the height

Tags: android, android-animation, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blue_pattern_repeated"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_splash_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_splash_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logo_exa"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_loader_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ivLogo"

            >
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

How can I send the @+id/layout_splash_content to the top of the parent?

I have this slide animation but in some devices is not working the top position, sometimes is not aligned to the top of the parent...

In some main activity:

```
    private void SlideUpLogo() {
    Slide(layoutSplashContent, -0.65f, null);
}
```

In base activity:

```
protected void Slide(View view, float toYValue, Animation.AnimationListener listener) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams viewLP = view.getLayoutParams();
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(viewLP);

    TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, lp.topMargin,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, toYValue);

    ta.setDuration(500);
    ta.setFillAfter(true);
    ta.setAnimationListener(listener);
    view.startAnimation(ta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way how ConstraintLayout works. MATCH_PARENT holds no value in case of constraint layout. In above case your layout "@+id/layout_splash_container" should look as follows,

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layout_splash_container"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
android:padding="8dp">
```

which will occupy all available width and height of the parent. You can also try using Relative or Frame layout for simple structures.

Comment: Thanks Pratik, It's working, But I have to remove the slide effect, There is a way to achieve that?..

Comment: What issue you are getting with animation? have u tried changing width of constraint layout to wrap_content?

Comment: Your answer is great, Now my layouts stretch to the height...but I want a soft slide up of the logo, but in some devices the value of the top is not the same...please checkout the slideUpLogo and slide methods...

Comment: You have set margin in dp, while in the code is fetching the top margin as float value. If m not wrong the system is expecting it to a px value while you are feeding it with dp value.

Comment: Thank you @Pratik and sorry for late, Finally I removed the animation, because cannot update the top and height for the layout that is slide to up...